# Lua multiple assignment with and without variable declaration

Tags: lua, neovim

Is there a way to accomplish the following:

```
local status, foo = pcall(require, "foo")
    ...
local status, bar = pcall(require, "bar") <-error here: Redefined local 'status'
```

In the second line, is there a way to describe only `bar` as being a new local declaration?

Comment: I think this post will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842679/lua-multiple-assignment

Comment: Redefinition of local variables is not an error in Lua. It's just a [linter (luacheck) warning](https://luacheck.readthedocs.io/en/stable/warnings.html). Any reason not to use `do`-`end` to limit the scope of the `status` variable? `do local status, foo = pcall(require, "foo") ... end do local status, bar = pcall(require, "bar") ... end` should do the job.

Comment: Great idea. I think I'll use that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 steps to re-use `status` variable:

```lua
local status, foo = pcall(require, "foo")
(...)
local bar
status, bar = pcall(require, "bar")
```